# What is the keyboard shortcut for Safari to go back a webpage in iPadOS?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados

I just got an iPad Air, and I am struggling to find the keyboard shortcut to go back a webpage when using Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following Apple support article to learn how you can discover keyboard shortcuts available in the current context when using an external keyboard connected to your iPad:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT211096

> ### See keyboard shortcuts
>
> To see a list of shortcuts that you can use with an app, press and hold the Command ⌘ key when you use the app or on the Home screen.

To answer your question, the keyboard shortcut to go back a webpage is: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yeah thank you, I found the shortcut. (I have a spanish keyboard)